# Laravel, custom url, route and controller

Tags: laravel, url, view, controller, routes

Here what a try to do.
I need to generate an url based on an unique code stored in the database (product code - example : sd25eds1rtr2). The URL looks like :

```
website/product/sd25eds1rtr2/
```

I get the product code with $product->code.
In `web.php` I try to create a `route` that calls a `controller` that gives a `view`.

```
Route::get('/product', 'HomeController@productcode')
```

I don't know what's the proper way to create the url and the controller. I've tried many things but I still don't get the expected page.

Any tip ?

Comment: I think before posting a question you should read framework Docs (Laravel) https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do something like this and you simply don't use a **wildcard**?
`Route::get('/product/{code}', 'HomeController@somefunction');`

Now you can catch the code in your controllers function

```
public function somefunction($code)
{
    $product = Product::where('code', $code)->first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Pass a parameter into a controller you need add a variable into the route

```
Route::get('/product/{productCode}', 'HomeController@productcode');
```

and in you controller you can access this by doing

```
 public function productcode($productCode)
{
 // Do something here
}
```

More can be read about this on the docs
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass variable data in url and access it in your controller then you do

```
Route::get('/product/{productCode}', 'HomeController@productcode');
```

You can access the 'productCode' in controller like:

```
public function productcode($productCode)
{
    /* your method */
}
```

Checkout [laravel documentation for route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

> Route

```
 Route::match(['get','post'],'/yoururl/{key}', 'controllername@functionname');
```

> controller

```
public function yourfunctionname($key){ }
```

**This is the simplest way to access your key value**